# Custom whitespace-line-column for specific modes in whitespace-mode

Tags: whitespace-mode

I want to force whitespace-mode highlight line after 99 character in rust-mode (cuz this length recommended by guidelines). For other modes i want to leave this variable with default value(80). How can i do this?

Answer (score 4):

As erikstokes [correctly](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/31840/15748) points out, the variable that controls this behaviour is `whitespace-line-column`. If you unconditionally set this variable in your `user-init-file`, however, it will affect all modes.

The standard mechanism that Emacs provides for mode-specific customisations is [hooks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html). So, to modify the variable in question for `rust-mode` only, you can write something like the following:

```el
(add-hook 'rust-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq-local whitespace-line-column 99)))
```

or, in Emacs versions prior to 24.3:

```el
(add-hook 'rust-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set (make-local-variable 'whitespace-line-column) 99)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than whitespace-mode, try `column-enforce-mode` which can be installed from Emacs MELPA.  See https://github.com/jordonbiondo/column-enforce-mode for more details.

Comment: Why is that better than using whitespace-mode?

Answer (score 0):

The variable you want is `whitespace-line-column`:

> Specify column beyond which the line is highlighted.
>
> It must be an integer or nil.  If nil, the ‘fill-column’ variable value is
>   used.
>
> Used when ‘whitespace-style’ includes ‘lines’ or ‘lines-tail’.

Add `(setq whitespace-line-column 99)` to your `.emacs`.